Taylor Series of $\frac{2p + 2p^2}{2+2p+p^2}$
I am trying to expand the following:
$$
\frac{2p + 2p^2}{2+2p+p^2}.
$$
Using the Taylor series at $a=0$, I get:
$p - p^3/2 + p^4/2 - p^5/4 + \dots$.
But in the book, it is also equated to $p + p^3 + 2p^5 + p^7 + p^8 + ...$. How is this done?
EDIT: This is after the question was solved, but I forgot(lol) that $p=3,$ and this is from a $p$-adic analysis book

You got the right answer.

Indeed, but it doesn't answer the question (which was how the analysis in the book was done!)

@JoséCarlosSantos But how do I equate it to the expression provided in the book?

Does the book give the general form of the series? i.e. expressed as $$\sum_n a_n p^n$$

@Marco, Yes. The book is about p-adic numbers and is introducing the analogy between writing numbers in a base and the division of functions. The series you have mentioned is given right above the example.

Of you write the general terms maybe will be easier to understand. Also giving the title of the book would be iseful

@Marco How are the general terms related? I don't see it. And even if they do, how do you get to that?

The title of the book is "p-adic numbers: An introduction-Springer" by Fernando Quadros Gouvea

The series you found is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{(-1-i)^n+(-1+i)^n}{2^n}p^n$$ if you have the general form of the second series is easier to compare them and see if they are equal. If you give also the chapter of this example and the edition of the book one can check directly on it

@Marco Okay, this is equal indeed. Unfortunately, I am struggling to get the expression you obtained. Wolfram Alpha also suggested this series, but I am not sure how it got there.

Are we supposed to evaluate this for a particular value of $p$?  In $p$-adic analysis, that would be a typical problem.  Not a limit where $p \to 0$.

@GEdgar indeed. As Samos pointed out, we had p=3, a fact I completely overlooked earlier.

What is $p$? ...

@TorstenSchoeneberg, I am doing it from a book on p-adic numbers. here specifically, p=3

Since that makes a big difference, you should include that information in the question. All except the accepted answer use $p$ as a variable, which behaves differently.

Since the book is about $p$-adic numbers, it seems that $p$
should denote a prime number. Since the coefficients already
include $2$, the next prime number is $3$. Indeed, PARI/GP gets
$ gp -q
? p = 3; print((2*p+2*p^2)/(2+2*p+p^2) + O(p^9))
3 + 3^3 + 2*3^5 + 3^7 + 3^8 + O(3^9)

and this seems to be the series in the book given $p=3$. The
$p$-adic expansion has a period of $16$ which is confirmed by
$$ a := 1 - (p + 2p + 2p^3 + p^4 + p^5), \\
b := 1 - p(1 + p + p^2)(1 + p + p^2 + p^3 + p^4),\\
\frac{1 - p^{16}}{2 + 2p + p^2} =
(p^8 - 1)\left( a + \frac{b(p-3)}{2 + 2p + p^2}\right)\!. $$
The $p$-adic numbers have some similarities to the real numbers
as they are both completions of the rationals using a metric.
This is particularly true for finding radix or base expansions. For example, the base $p$ expansion of rational numbers is similar
to their $p$-adic expansion. Here is an example of expanding
$\,1/7 = .142857\dots\,$ as a $10$-adic number using PARI/GP:
? p = 10; /* set base to 10 */
? d = 9;  /* number of digits to 9 */
? a = 1; b = 7; /* numerator, denominator */
? digits(p^d * a\b + 1, p)
[1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 3]
? digits(truncate(O(p^d) + a/b), p)
[1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 3]

Here is the similar example you cited as a $3$-adic number:
? p = 3; /* set base to 3 */
? d = 9;  /* number of digits to 9 */
? a = 2*p+2*p^2; b = 2+2*p+p^2; /* numerator, denominator */
? digits(p^d * a\b + 5, p)
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
? digits(truncate(O(p^d) + a/b), p)
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
? p = 'p; Vec(p + p^3 + 2*p^5 + p^7 + p^8)
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

To do it 'by hand' the $3$-adic computation would be similar to this:
               220  =  a =        2p^2 + 2p + 0
               122  =  b =        1p^2 + 2p + 2
              1021  = 2b = 1p^3 + 0p^2 + 2p + 1

               220  =  a
            - 122   = - p^1 b
==================
      ...222222 
          - 122     = - p^3 b
==================
    ...222221 
       - 1021       = - 2p^5 b
==================
  ...222212
      - 122         = - p^7 b
==================
...2222202
     - 122          = - p^8 b
==================
..2222201
   - 1021           = - 2p^9 b
==================
..222111

a - (p + p^3 + 2p^5 + p^7 + p^8 + 2p^9)b = O(p^10)
a/b = p + p^3 + 2p^5 + p^7 + p^8 + 2p^9 + O(p^10)

By the way, the Taylor expansion you gave is closely related
to the OEIS sequence A090132 which
has a generating function of $\,(1+2 x)/(1+2 x+2 x^2).\,$ This
can be verified using PARI/GP:
? p = 2*x; (2*p+2*p^2)/(2+2*p+p^2) == p*(1+2*x)/(1+2*x+2*x^2)
1


Oh my god! We just need to put p=3 in the series? Nice

I just realised. How did you actually get the series 3+3^3+2*3^5+...? I glanced over the answer and missed this. We cannot directly substitute right? I am sure I am missing something fundamentally dumb, but I do not see the relevance of the O(p^9) or even really what it means.

@NaitikMundra Thanks for that comment! I have added more code which should be self-explanatory.

I understand the code. Rather, I was wondering how I would get to this by hand.

Thank you so much. You are a lifesaver

Firstly,
$$f(p)=\dfrac{2p+p^2}{2+2p+p^2}=1-\dfrac2{2+2p+p^2},$$
$$f(q\sqrt2)=1-\dfrac1{1+q\sqrt2+q^2}.\tag1$$
Taking in account the generating function for Chebyshev Polynomials of the Second Kind in the form of
$$\dfrac1{1-2xt+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\text U_n(x)\,t^n,\tag2$$
easily to get
$$f(q\sqrt2)=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,
\text U_n\left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)\,q^n 
=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\text U_n\left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)\,q^n,$$
wherein
$$\text U_n(x)=\dfrac{\sin\big((n+1)\arccos(x)\big)}{\sin(\arccos(x))},$$
$$\text U_n\left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right) =\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac34\pi(n+1)\right)}{\sin\left(\dfrac34\pi\right)}
=-\sqrt2\cos\left(\dfrac34\pi(n-1)\right),$$
$$f(p)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\sqrt2\cos\left(\dfrac34\pi(n-1)\right)\,\left(\dfrac p{\sqrt2}\right)^n,$$
$$f(p)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n p^{n+1},\tag3$$
$$c_n=\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^n\cos\left(\dfrac34\,n\pi\right) .\tag4$$

WA test confirms the obtained result.

Looking at the graphs of the function to expand and two expansions, we can see that your expansion looks correct and the expansion provided in the book is unrelated.

But, since the book is devoted to $p$-adic numbers, I guess the series expansion provided in the book
should be considered not in the field $\mathbb R$ of the real numbers, but in the field $\mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers. Indeed, we have
$$(2+2p+p^2)(p + p^3 + 2p^5 + p^7 + p^8)=$$ $$
2p+2p^2+3p^3+2p^4+5p^5+4p^6+4p^7+4p^8+3p^9+p^{10}.$$
Although the expansion provided in the book still looks strange, because in the product the low powers of $p$ after $2p+2p^2$ should vanish.
